# find and connect to wireless camera

Tags: wireless, networking, camera

I've got an old wireless camera/baby monitor... (4 years old)

Worked with an old windows machine that quit some time ago. On the old windows machine it connected via a wireless dongle and software installed from a cd.

Is it possible to:

1. Pick up / send communication to the wireless camera? How would I even find it, its not connected to the router.
2. Access the camera wirelessly without the dongle, its broken.

The camera is on, I did a nmap on my router but no ip is assigned to it. There is no USB to connect to the cam. Its strictly wireless. I am on a laptop with wireless, hoping there is a way to connect. directly via wireless.

The goal is to have this running as a baby monitor again.. Any suggestions welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can find documentation about the camera indicating that it uses a standard for wireless such as bluetooth or wifi, it probably isn't compatible with anything else.  You might be able to get a replacement from ebay or the manufacturer.

My advice to you would be to look into modern alternatives.  dlink sells a wireless security camera for only about $25, although I've seen them as slow as $15, which is pretty easy to setup with ubuntu, windows or mac.  If the camera doesn't need to be wireless, you can pick usb webcams as low as $3 if you don't mind shopping around.

In the meantime let's see what we can find out about yours.  Please take a close look at yours and report back with the brand, model, etc.  I can't look it up based on your description.  "OLD" isn't quite detailed enough.

**Rest of the answer:**
Thank you for providing the brand and model.  I believe I have discovered all that you need.  It seems that even if this product is discontinued, which does not seem to be the case, [the company](http://mylevana.com/Contact_Us.eng.html) is still around so you can probably order a replacement receiver.  I've also found [the user manual](http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/shoptronics/lvtw500-manual.pdf) in PDF format which you can read as I have done.  It doesn't appear that the wireless system used is directly compatible with home wifi routers so it would seem you need to acquire a replacement receiver.

Comment: This is the camera: Levana LV-TW500 Digital Wireless Baby Camera with Online Monitoring and Email.

Found it on amazon:
http://www.amazon.ca/Levana-LV-TW500-Digital-Wireless-Monitoring/dp/B00303GBO8

But the dongle is broken so all I have is the cam. Lost the software too. Hoping there is a way to connect and monitor again. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! So the dongle miraculously decided to work again. But I have no idea what I need to do to get this going in ubuntu as I have no drivers.

lsusb for this returns:
ID 0c45:6710 Microdia

.. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now that you've told me that the dongle is working I'll look to see if there are linux drivers for it. I wouldn't be surprised, actually because the device is as old as it is.  In fact you might find that for a device that old there aren't up to date drivers for it that would work with windows. At this very moment I'm in the middle of something else so I'll have to get back to you.  In the meantime check your usb ports.  It is possible that the port where you tried the dongle before is dirty or bent.

Comment: Found the original software/drivers here: https://mylevana.com/product/Digital_Wireless_Baby_Monitor.eng-66-download.html

They are WINDOWS drivers however, so to make it work with Linux you'll have to install WINE.  Fortunately I'm an expert with that so I'll give you the best tips to ensure success.  First DO NOT INSTALL WINE.  Mild contradiction there.  You need to instead install WINETRICKS from the software center.  Winetricks both installs WINE and everything you need to make WINE work.  Then after you download the software/drivers you need, there is a fairly good chance it will work.

Comment: I already have wine installed and use it for a few programs. the driver does not work with wine - Install fails - I'm hesitant to uninstall, and concerned installing winetricks after the fact may not work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Guage, you simply cannot install winetricks after you have installed wine.  It won't let you.  You have only three options, uninstall wine then install winetricks, settle for a wine installation that won't work nearly as well as it could, or spend the next 5 weeks researching every little package winetricks would have installed for you, and manually install all that stuff by hand.

Comment: uninstalled wine and installed winetricks (all prior programs still work well) but no go on the dongle install. Still not recognizing it. Maybe it is still broken, but it shows up in lsusb... so it should be working.

Comment: Sadly, there are many programs written for windows which will only run with windows os.  On the other hand, if you have enough hardware around, you can SAFELY install windows and simply never connect it to the internet.  Another thing you might try is to nag the manufacturer to make their product Linux Friendly.